# Git: Squash commits older than conflicting merge

Tags: git, git-rebase, squash, git-squash

I would like to squash some commits that are older than a "conflicting" merge. E.g.:

```
main branch:  A--B--C--D--G--H
dev branch:    \-E--F----/
```

H is my current head, G is the conflicting merge (so a merge in which I resolved conflicts manually) and I would like to squash C and D - but if I try to do that, I'm getting rebase conflicts which are due to G having been a conflicting merge.

Can I squash C and D anyways and if yes, how? I would be interested in a solution in which I do not have to merge something manually again.

Additional info: `git rebase -i B` does not even work when leaving all commits on "pick" - which should do nothing, right?

Comment: first step : add `-r` (short for `--rebase-merges`) option to your `git rebase` command. Without it, `git rebase` will simply drop merge commits from the list of replayed commits.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, that's the first step and it solves at least the problem that it does not even work when not changing anything in the git editor (not changing any "pick") - but it does not solve my problem of conflicts when squashing C and D.

Comment: second : since there is no content change, if you hit again a merge conflict trying to merge `F` and `<new C>`, you just have to use the same content as `G` : try something like `git restore --staged --source G -- .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use rebase for this, rebase can squash for you but it's built for much heavier lifting than ancestry-only rewrites like this, it does a load of (slow) prep work to enable any alterations you like along the way.

```
git replace --graft G B F   # (put usable references to those commits here of course)
git filter-branch
```

and you've achieved everything the rebase would, *vastly* quicker.

Answer (score 1):

First : by default, `git rebase` completely ignores merge commits. You have to specify [`-r | --rebase-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--r) to make `git rebase` "aware" of your merge actions.

Combined with `-i` : you will see that the sequencer script is a bit more elaborate, and allows you to describe the actions you want to take to replay your merges.

---

Second : in the scenario you describe, the content of the commits to merge will be the same as the original commits, so "solving conflicts" is equivalent to : "re-use the exact same content as `G`".

If you hit a conflict when merging : try running

```
git restore --staged --source G -- .
# or using shorthands :
git restore -S -s G -- .
```

You may need to run `git reset .` beforehand if you need to clear the "conflicting" flags from files in the index.

If your local git doesn't have `git restore` (this command was added fairly recently, in git 2.27 -- june 2020) : try

```
git read-tree G
```

which should place the content of `G` in the index.